# Средняя частота запросов RSS агрегаторов

Tags: rss

Заметил, что многие RSS "читалки", получают новость уже почти сразу после опубликования на сайте:

- Неужели они настолько часто
     обращаются к ресурсу за обновлением?
     (Сам использую RSS Feed Reader в
     Chrome). Как часто, в среднем, происходят обращения?
- Как можно снизить частоту запросов на
     стороне сервера? Или использовать другие методы оптимизации?
- Способно ли большое число подписчиков
     "подгрузить" сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как можно снизить частоту запросов на стороне сервера?

Это - задача читалки. Потому как не нужно сразу лезть всё выкачивать, а надо использовать If-Modified-Since (некоторые делают сначала HEAD и смотрят Last-Modified). Соответственно, сервер должен корректно отдавать Last-Modified.

Comment: Ну а если контент выдается динамически, и при запросе в базу все равно придется лезть, чтобы посмотреть, не было ли обновы? Нельзя ли установить время которое оптимально для обновления?

Comment: Во-первых, клиент никак не может знать, с какой частотой обновляется RSS (как вариант - отдавать специальное значение item, например, но это частный и не универсальный случай). Во-вторых, в over 9000 случаев можно отдавать статику вместо динамики. И в-третьих, Last-Modified в RSS присутствует по определению (самая свежая pubDate), а это дело можно хранить отдельно, и в любом случае отдавать быстро даже в случае динамики.